# custom class variable and GUI textfields

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an applet that allows a user to search for an Employee, and if not found add the employee. The user then can grant server privileges to that employee. This is done by adding the employee created from the Employee class into a arraylist. The server hashmap has a string server name as the key and the value is an arraylist of employees.
Heres my problem. 
I want the value the user enters into a JOptionPane input box to be the variable for the employee examp

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(EmpText,"Enter Employee ID");
Employee EmpText = new Employee(firstName, lastName);
```

This code however just uses the text "EmpText" and not the entered value by the user. 
I have tired

```
String emp=EmpText.getText();
Employee emp=new Employee(String, String);
```

doesnt work basically I want

```
Employee (input from JOption input dialog) =new Employee(String, String);
```

Comment: tell me if you want your InputDialog to input?

Comment: you can use an object of this to use to input data from it like 
          
        JOptionPane jpan=new JOptionPane(); 
use jpan object to input data you can

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create variable names.

You could create a HashMap that uses the name you enter to access the Employee record.

So the code would be something like:

```
HashMap<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
```

Then when you ask for the employee name

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
Employee employee = new Employee(...);
employees.put(name, employee);
```

When you want to access the employee you do:

```
Employee employee = employees.get(...);
```